# How to connect a controller to a Openflow Topology using Pi with minimal ports?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi3, openflow

I'm trying to setup an OpenFlow enabled topology using Raspberry Pi3 as switches, and an external POX controller running on my PC. The topology is as follows.

[image: Physical testbed using Raspberry Pis]

Now the continuous lines are data paths which are basically RJ45 cables.
The dashed lines are the control lines which receive OpenFlow messages from the controller.

My question is how should I connect all the switches to the controller. Is it by

1. Direct connnection (a network inside a network). In my case, there needs to be 1 LAN cable from each switch to the controller. Total 4 LAN wires to the controller
2. Use the existing PiSwitch network. 1 extra LAN cable between the controller and any one of the switch.

The problem with (1) is that it's not scalable with increasing number of switches

The problem with (2) is that the network needs some pre-information regarding the controller's location during startup. One switch will become too much loaded in this case.

How is it done in real life when the number of switches is very high?

Comment: Bumping the post

Comment: Rebumping it once more